# :last-child selector working on some pages but not others

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I want all but the last of a series of posts on a Wordpress page to have simple dividers between them, which I've implemented using a bottom border.

I've used last-child to remove the border on the last post of each page, and it works on some posts but not others.

The last post on [the homepage](http://juliamariani.com/) has no bottom border as intended, but on the [tag pages](http://juliamariani.com/tag/print/) the last post seems to totally ignore the :last-child selector. It also doesn't work in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GPB8M/).

Markup is basically this:

```
<div id="full-width">
 <article id="post-250" class="post">
   Post here
 </article>
 <article id="post-245" class="post">
   Post here
 </article>
 <div class="pagination clearfix">
 </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
article.post {
   padding-bottom: 60px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

article.post:last-child {
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   border-bottom: 0 none; 
}
```

I'm not sure if it has something to do with the pagination div below the articles (which will start to serve a purpose when there's more content), but that's a div and not an article so shouldn't be affected by my article.post:last-child selector.

Even stranger - the first article on each tag page responds to being targeted with a :first-child selector, but the last article doesn't respond to :last-child.

I can't figure out why what looks like a very similar generated markup between the homepage and the tag page works in one case and doesn't in the other.

My CSS validates fully.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: That's because it's not the last child in the second link. `.pagination .clearfix` is. Put that div outside like in the first link and it'll work

Comment: does article:last-child not target the last child *of type* article? Is there an alternative?

Comment: No, then you would use `:last-of-type`

Comment: Somehow I managed to miss the existence of :last-of-type. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:last-child` means litteraly the *last child*, the last child element of its container. On the page where you said `:last-child` doesn't work you have another div as last child (more speicically `<div class="pagination clearfix">`).

#### There are two solutions, as I see it:

**1.** If you don't want to change your markup, you could just use `article:last-of-type` instead of `article.post:last-child`.

**2.** Move `<div class="pagination clearfix">` out of that container.

Comment: :last-of-type is what I'm looking for. In this instance I *think* moving the pagination outside the article container would break the pagination functionality though there may be a way round it.

Answer (score 0):

:last-child match last child of it's parent element, not the "last of it's kind"

You could try

```
 // This match and article with post class followed by anotherarticle with post class 
 article.post + article.post { 
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
 }

 // This match and article with post class followed by a div
 article.post + div {
   border-bottom:...
```

Or use :last-of-type, but I'm unsure about how well it is supported.

Comment: This will presumably remove the bottom border from every other article, which is no good when there are more than two of them! :last-of-type seems like my only option since in this case moving the pagination div outside of the container would also mean moving it outside the Wordpress loop, breaking pagination.